# How can I stop iOS Safari from keeping the cursor in the topleft pixel of the browser pane?

Tags: ios, css, mobile-safari, cursor-position

I have a website, http://ADHD.BHStudios.org, which has a sidebar that is supposed to stay hidden until you hover your mouse cursor over it (pure CSS). However, in iOS Safari, the browser pane is always told the cursor is in the topleft pixel, which forces this sidebar to always stay open, rather than when the user touches it to give it focus. **How can I stop iOS Safari from keeping the cursor in the topleft pixel of the browser pane, and how can I keep the "touch-to-expand" capability after doing so?** Other browsers and other operating systems do not have this issue. Tested on iPad 2, iPad 3, and iPhone 4s with iOS 5 and 6. Again, this works on other mobile browsers and other mobile devices, such as Opera Mobile (iOS and Android), Chrome (iOS and Android), and the default Android 2.2 Browser.

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone has a different layout, but on iPad, the sidebar is never open. So, I'm unable to replicate that part of your problem.

As for the hover issue, obviously there's no hover pseudo-class on a touchscreen device. You have to attach an event listener to the touchstart event

```
document.getElementById('top').addEventListener('touchstart', function(){...});
```

You can set a timer for it to disappear (put this inside your touchstart callback):

```
 setTimeout(function(){...}), [milliseconds]);
```

That's how I'd do it.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to keep this site JS-less. I'm surprised you're not having this problem, as it seems a constant for me. The `:hover` pseudoclass works fine on other touch browsers, like I siad, just not Safari.

Comment: But how can "hover" work on a touchscreen device? From the DOM's perspective the user is either "clicking" ("touchstart" event) or not interacting at all. There's no touchscreen equivalent of mouseover. How does mobile chrome simulate hovering on a touchscreen (I'm not asking rhetorically, I'm an iOS guy and I'm curious). Here's a guide to mobile safari events: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html

Comment: You can "hover" on a touchscreen device, like an Android tablet, by touching what you want to hover over. It will generate a hover and click event (and active and focus if the DOM element supports those). It's considered a hover because the non-Safari browser moves a virtual cursor wherever you touch. Try loading my site up on an Android tablet and you'll see what I mean.